# How to get Gmail compose poup To and Cc email address using Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a Gmail addon using chrome extension for our product using javascript. I want to read To and Cc emails from Gmail Inbox and want to display some information on the Gmail page from our product.

My question is, how I get the To and Cc email address from the Gmail inbox?

I spent a lot of time in googling but not found any solution. If anyone has worked on any such thing or has any idea, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother googling just Start Reading here: `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app`.  You may not understand everything at first but stick with it.